# undefined index of php $id get value of the variable

Tags: php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$conn) {
    die("KO" . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "select * from tblabc where id = '$id'";

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0){
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
}
?>
```

this is my code to editing the table record. but when its executed occurs error "notice: Undefined index: id".
how to resolved this issued. thx

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the `id` value to this page via `$_GET`  ? What does `var_dump($_GET['id'])`  give you ?

Comment: You should echo your  $_GET['id']; may be it is not set

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL-injection just imagine (don't try) someone asking for the id `';DROP TABLE tblabc -- `

Comment: @maximus: var dump result null

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: thx for ur advise, for study only not for real word usage

Comment: @mogleng the fact that it's not for study is no excuse to write insecure code - because that way, you *learn* to write insecure code. you should instead do it the right way from the very beginning.

Comment: ok thx 4 ur concern.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);

if (!$conn) {
    die("KO" . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if(isset($_GET))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "select * from tblabc where id = '$id'";

if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0){
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
}
}
else
{
 echo 'nothing received';
}
?>
```

Use the above code to check the validity of the get variable before using it.This way you'll be able to know where the error is coming from.

Comment: ur code response : Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\web\edit.php on line 30
ok

Comment: please tell me the url of the page you are running this script in

Comment: http://localhost/web/edit.php

Comment: solved. thx for the assistant

Answer (score 0):

you should try with this

```
$id  = '';
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != '')
{
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $sql = "select * from tblabc where id = '$id'";

    if (mysqli_num_rows($sql)==0){
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
    }
}
else
{
echo 'Id Not Defined';
}
```

Comment: ur code respone id not defined.

Comment: yes because of your $_GET['id'] is not set.. please check in URL or other source where form id come to this page

Comment: and how to check it?

Comment: solved. thx for the assistant